# Possibly incorrect result of DiscreteLimit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

In version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
DiscreteLimit[Product[Sum[1/2^k, {k, 0, i}], {i, 1, n}]/2^n,n -> Infinity]
```

> `Indeterminate`

The above is not in accordance with numeric calculations

```
N[Table[Product[Sum[1/2^k, {k, 0, i}], {i, 1, n}]/2^n, {n, 10, 100,10}], 15]
```

> `{0.577858301626197, 0.577576465583082, 0.577576190442160,  0.577576190173467, 0.577576190173205, 0.577576190173205,  0.577576190173205, 0.577576190173205, 0.577576190173205,  0.577576190173205}`

It should be noticed that `0.577576190173205` is not identified as `N[EulerGamma]`. Also

```
DiscreteMaxLimit[Product[Sum[1/2^k, {k, 0, i}], {i, 1, n}]/2^n,n -> Infinity]
```

is running without any response for a long time. So is `Indeterminate` correct?

Comment: Reported as a bug/suggestion to improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
 func = DiscreteLimit[Product[Sum[1/2^k, {k, 0, i}] // ExpandAll, {i, 1, n}]/2^n, n -> Infinity]

 (*2 QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2]*)

 N[func - EulerGamma, 100] // FunctionExpand
 (*0.00036052527167198195128735377605912913566447374144796942371489748493\
   67550360293542035386230949494068989*)
```

Look like is not a **EulerGamma**

Comment: Thank you. I am  out of Mathematica so I  will draw a decision later.